# Not sure how to reference object for `slideDown,js` operation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle, slidedown

I have a JS function that expands a list item once clicked as follows:

```
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#improved .head').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              alert($(this).closest('li').find('.content').not(':animated'));
              $(this).closest('li').find('.content').not(':animated').slideToggle();
            });
          }); 
      </script>
```

I want a button that expands (slides down) each element whether its slide attribute is toggled on or off, but i do not know how to get a reference to these elements.

I tried creating a button that calls this function,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          function ExpandForPrinting() {
          for (header in $(this).closest('li').find('.content').not(':animated')){

          header.slideDown();

          }           
          }
      </script>
```

But it did not work. Whats the correct way to get the references to these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using JQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead:

```
function ExpandForPrinting() {
   $(document).find('.content').not(':animated').each(function(){
      $(this).slideDown();
   });
}
```

I think this would also work:

```
function ExpandForPrinting() {
   $(document).find('.content').not(':animated').slideDown();
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I see that the correct way of getting references to items is `$('body').find(...`. Thank you.

Comment: @user3163380 Glad I could help. Yes, or using `$(document).find(...`. Like in my updated answer.